# C6386 warning in visual studio 2019 C language and run time error

Tags: c

"Warning    C6386   Buffer overrun while writing to 'temp':  the writable size is '80' bytes, but '-1' bytes might be written."

The func supposed to recive a string and to create a new string with only even words for the source string.

```c
char* evenlength(const char* str)
{

    int i = 0, j = 0, k, count;
    char temp[MAX], * res;

    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        count = 0;
        if (str[i] == ' ')
            i++;
        else
        {
            for (k = i; str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\0'; i++)
                count++;

            if (count % 2 == 0)
            {
                while (k < i)
                {
                    temp[j] = str[k];
                    j++;
                    k++;
                }
                temp[j] = ' ';
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
    } //here is the warning line:
    temp[j - 1] = '\0';
    res = (char*)malloc(strlen(temp) * sizeof(char) + 1);
    if (res == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR! heap is full.....");
        exit(1);
    }
    res = temp;
    return res;
}
```

this is one out of three func in this program, after printing all results (correctly) the program then crashes.

[image].

Comment: If `str` is empty, the `j == 0` and `temp[j - 1] = '\0';` invokes undefined behavior. (thus the warning)

Comment: What is your question? The compiler already told you what the error is.

Comment: If `str` is an empty string, the while loop is never run and you are accessing `temp[-1]`, which is exactly what the compiler tells you.